# Any German dict like Webster?

Tags: vocabulary, dictionary

I'm a beginner of German and I wonder whether there is any dictionary as important as the Webster in English, which I found is extremely useful when I was preparing my GRE test.

Comment: Und was ist Webster, hat es Eigenschaften die man aufzählen kann, auf die es Dir ankommt?

Comment: @userunknown Ist deine Frage rhetorisch? Ich denke schon, dass du Webster kennst. Wenn du darauf hinweisen willst, dass es nicht jeder kennt und man mehr darauf in der Frage darauf eingehen sollte, kann man das auch anders machen...

Comment: @Em1... wo ist denn das Problem mit der Nachfrage? In der Frage steht ja tatsächlich nur die Wichtigkeit. Langenscheidt würde sein Wörterbuch sicher auch wichtig finden, genauso wie Pons ihrs und so weiter.

Comment: @Em1: Nein, ich kenne Webster nicht. Da es sich nicht um ein dt. Wörterbuch oder dgl. handelt zähle ich dieses Wissen auch nicht zu dem, was von jmd. der antworten möchte erwartet werden kann. Ich halte es auch insgesamt für schlechten Stil nur den Produktnamen zu nennen und davon auszugehen, dass die Leser besser wissen als man selbst, was damit gemeint ist, denn dieser Webster kann ja mehr als ein Merkmal haben - welches ist dann gemeint? Preis, Aktualität, Ausführlichket, Knappheit, Einsprachigkeit, Satz, Bilder, Hinweise zur Aussprache, ....

Comment: maybe [THIS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_bedeutender_W%C3%B6rterb%C3%BCcher#Aktuelle_W.C3.B6rterb.C3.BCcher_zur_deutschen_Sprache) helps

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, yes my intention is to find a monolingual dictionary with near-precise definitions to every word. Thank you @Em1

Answer (score 5):

There is only one monolingual German dictionary of substance and importance, the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/).

Comment: I prefer Wahrig.

Comment: I prefer ÖWB. But it's hardly the go-to solution for a learner of German.

Comment: Seriously? Never heard of the "Deutsches Wörterbuch": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch ? Surely I wouldn't recommend it for beginner's use, but it does have plenty of substance and importance.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at my 3-Volume Webster I'm afraid, there is currently no counterpart (observing the decline of printed reference works like Britannica and Brockhaus this is not going to improve). In my opinion the closest match is the big Wahrig (ISBN 978-3577102414). In contrast to Webster it has nearly no diagrams of the objects described, just textual explanations, but it is not difficult to find the former in Wikipedia. At all occasions tried I was disappointed by German Wiktionary, if you want online information concerning word frequency and in which combinations a word is most likely used I recommend [Deutscher Wortschatz](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/) by Leipzig University.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is pretty useful: http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch
Hope it helps.

Comment: Pons provides a monolingual dictionary. This is rather what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Em1... or so you think ;)

Answer (score -1):

Another popular, easy to use solution is http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html or http://www.dict.cc

Comment: You don't know Webster, do you?